# Counting trailing new line characters in a string

Tags: python, string, nlp

Hello I have a python string in such a way

```
s = "Hello world\n\n"
```

I want to count the number of trailing new line characters in the string in this case it is **2**.
If I use `s.strip()` it just removes new lines and returns the string but not how many new line characters it has removed in the process.
How to get the count as well as remove the trailing new line characters.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
>>> s = "Hello world\n\n"
>>> s.rstrip("\n")
'Hello world'
```

Then just check the difference:

```
>>> s = "Hello world\n\n"
>>> len(s) - len(s.rstrip("\n"))
2
```

Comment: Upvote. The only correct solution here for *trailing* new line

Comment: All answers seem to work but just that rather than using count to find "\n" using difference between lengths seems to be faster. Don't know if there is any specific reason. Since I work with latency I consider this for me thanks.

Comment: @RaghavendraSugeeth, count iterates over the string while the lenght of it is cached (since they are inmutable). That is why it is faster

Answer (score 0):

The method I use to remove any "\n", "\t" and other unwanted characters is:

```
def filterText(text):
    return " ".join(text.split(" "))

filterText("Hello \n\n\nWorld\tI\n\nLike money\t")
```

output:

```
Hello World I Like money
```

Really comes in handy in web scraping.

Answer (score -1):

```
s = "Hello world\n\n" 
s.count('\n')
```

Returns 2

Then

```
s.strip('\n')
```

Comment: `s.strip('\n')` also removes  newlines only... and OP wants to have a way of something with only one method...

Answer (score -2):

You can count the number of newline characters before removing them.

```
count = s.count("\n");
```

which should return the number of new lines.

Comment: OP wants a method that counts newlines and removes newlines altogether.

Comment: ah, OP wasnt too specific about that, or i miss understood.

Comment: s.count() counts *all* newline characters, also those occurring somewhere in the middle of the string, not just the trailing ones as specified by OP.

Answer (score -2):

Quick, but perhaps "dirty", is to do it in two steps:

```
s = "Hello world\n\n"
s.count("\n")
```

Count: 2

Followed by

```
s.strip("\n")
```

Comment: I think that splitting in two steps is not dirty at all. @U9-Forward as strings are immutable, there is no such method. Methods that apply a transformation on a string returns the new string.

Comment: @ U9-Foward I do not really agree that OP explicitly asks to do it in one method.